# Distribution of x * Pr(x) for Normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

This must be a standard problem, but I can't find an answer.

I'm assuming that particle weights follow a Normal frequency distribution, that is the *number* of particles with weight < x is given by N(x), which is a CDF, the integral of the pdf n(x).

I want the *weight* of particles with weight < x. I think this CDF will be the integral of x*n(x), but I've no idea how to calculate that.

Any suggestions?

Edited to add: As pointed out by @scherm the total weight particles with weight < x depends on the sample size. I should have said that the total weight of all particles is known, so I want the *proportion* of the total weight which is made up of particles with weight

Comment: To clarify:  do you want the average weight, or the distribution of the weights, given that the weight < x?

Comment: If the _number_ of particles with weight < x is N(x; mean, sd) [assume Normal CDF] I want the total _weight_ of particles with weight < x, as a function of x, mean, and sd.

Comment: @a_statistician I don't think so. I think the expression you give is just the integral of n(y)dy [the Normal pdf] between −∞ and x, which is just the Normal CDF. I think I want the integral of y.n(y)dy between those limits.

Comment: What you want is truncated mean. it is $\int_{-\infty}^xyn(y)dy$. There is no analytical expression for this integral. Maybe you can find an online calculator for this question. ---Find a way to edit it: Delete and re-type.

Answer (score 2):

The total weight of particles weighing at most $x$ depends on your sample. Perhaps what you are looking for is the mean of these weights.

Given the distribution of weights $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, we can compute this analytically. We use the expectation of the lower tail of the [truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) (assuming $\mu$ is far enough away from 0 that the probability of a negative weight is very small):

$$
E(X|X<x)=\mu-\frac{\phi\left(\beta\right)}{\Phi\left(\beta\right)},
$$

where $\beta=(x-\mu)/\sigma$.

Let's verify this in MATLAB:

```
rng(1)
mu = 100;
sigma = 10;
n = 100000;
x = 80; % cutoff value
X = mu + sigma*randn([n,1]);
mean(X(X<x)) % 76.1884

% analytical solution:
beta = x-mu;
mu-sigma*normpdf(beta/sigma)/normcdf(beta/sigma) % 76.2678
```

Comment: Hmm. I can do it numerically. I don't have MATLAB but in R I did:

Comment: Hmm. I [think I] can do it numerically, but I'd thought this would have been addressed elsewhere - truncated normal is a good idea. In R I did: `xPrx <- function(x, mean = 14, sd = 5){
   integrate(function(y) y*dnorm(y, mean=mean, sd=sd), lower = 0, upper = x)$value/
   integrate(function(y) y*dnorm(y, mean=mean, sd=sd), lower = 0, upper = Inf)$value
}` where I've (a) used values appropriate to my application (b) integrated from zero to avoid negative weights (c) scaled to proportion of the total. Plugging in your values I don't get your answer. I'll keep playing and reading.

Comment: I'm not familiar with R, but this ratio of expectations seems strange to me. Perhaps [this package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=truncnorm) may be helpful to you. Either way, after seeing your edit to the original question, I think you're just looking for the cdf of the weights evaluated at $x$, i.e., $\Phi((x-\mu)/\sigma)$, where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf. This gives you $\Pr(X\leq x)$, the probability that a particle weighs at most $x$.

Comment: The cdf is the number proportion of particles weight < x. I want the weight proportion of particles weight < x. Expectation (=mean) of a truncated Normal is a good steer, but is the average height of the pdf curve in that range, I want the area under the curve. With your hints I think it's straightforward, but I won't have time to try until Tuesday when I'll comment further.

Comment: Delayed by a dose of campylobacter - not fun! I think there's a σ missing from your equation. Also, that seems to break for x > mean. In the end I met the need with numerical integration of y*normcdf(y) between -Inf and x; ugly but it worked. Thanks for your input. I haven't accepted the answer because it didn't meet my needs, but I have upvoted it.